# How Can I Transfer a File From Google Bucket to Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: windows, server, google-cloud-storage, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have set up a Windows server on Google Cloud. I also have a Google Storage Bucket. I want to transfer a zip to the VM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. Follow the directions to create your VM and storage bucket.

Start your vm and rdp into the server. THEN from WITHIN the VM instance run:

```
\Google\Cloud SDK>gsutil -m cp -r gs://[bucket]/[your file] C:/users/[computer name]/[location]
```

Replace `[computer name]` with your user's name on windows, and replace `[location]` with the location you want to transfer the file to.